# 2D array using pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

This is the program given in my textbook for illustrating 2-D array using pointers:

```
int *val,r,c;//r= number of rows,c= number of columns
val=new int[r*c]
for(int i=0;i<r;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++)
    {
        cin>>val[i*c+j];
    }
}
```

Here although they are discussing about a 2D array, the pointer is still 1D. Secondly, `new` allocates the pointer `val` with specified size in free store.

```
cin>>val[i*c+j];
```

shouldn't it be

```
cin>>*val[i*c+j];
```

because I am taking value for the given memory location not the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `val` is not a 2-dimensional array as you said; it is indeed 1-dimensional.  However, it can be treated as a 2-dimensional array *flattened* into a 1-dimensional array in [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

Regarding your second question, the correct way of accessing an element in this "2D" array is

```
val[i * c + j]
```

not

```
*val[i * j + c]
```

This is because `ptr[n]` is *by definition* equivalent to `*(ptr + n)`, so the dereferencing is already included.  Additionally, for a row-major "2D" array the relative position of each element is given by `i * c + j` not `i * j + c` since each time you increase in the row number, the index needs to skip forward by `c`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand the second point. I am assigning a value right? so shouldn't it be: *a=2

Comment: `cin` accepts not a pointer, but a *reference*.  The expression `ptr[n]` is *already dereferenced*, so the extra `*` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

`c` is the size of each row. So row `0` starts at `val[0]` (0*c), row `1` starts at `val[c]` (1*c), row `2` starts at `val[2*c]`. The formula is correct.

Comment: usually its *a=6 and a=&b if a is a pointer. But for pointer array, why is it val[i*c+j]=1 not *val[i*c+j]=1? i am storing the value right.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ to assign a value for just pointer variable you use  *  in-front of variable name. but for use an array you do not need to use  *  in-front of variable name to assign value to an array.

Comment: i mean not for a pointer , but for assign value to an dynamic array (which you call array using pointers) in c++ . As I know the implementation of int pointer is differ from dynamic array. correct me if i'm wrong.